# jQuery - add onclick to TR

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I use Richfaces and one of the rich:dataTable generates this html:

```
<form id="scheduleForm">
  <table id="scheduleForm:rowList">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I want to act on a click on a TR for this table. How can I do this?
The following also works for other tables on the page and I get the alert() for the other rows as well, and I don't want that.

```
        jQuery('#scheduleForm:rowList tr').click(function(event) {
            alert(1);
        });
```

About the ':' char. It is generated by Richfaces.

The original code is:

```
<h:form id="scheduleForm">
<rich:dataTable id="rowList">
</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I think the ":" might be playing some thing here. If I am not wrong ":" is some meta char and have some meaning in the selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the `:` is generated by JSF / RichFaces. I've had trouble with that `:` before as well. It is probably not what the jQuery folks expected in an ID. They're using it for selectors. What you may want to do is this:

```
jQuery('table[id = "scheduleForm:rowList"] tr').click(...)
```

Check out http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2009/04/tips-and-tricks-on-jquery-and-richfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

try the following, It would help you.

```
jQuery(document.getElementById('scheduleForm:rowList').getElementsByTagName('tr')).click(function(event) {
          alert(1);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the below, give the tr an id.

```
<form id="scheduleForm">
  <table id="scheduleForm:rowList">
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

jQuery('#tr1').click(function(event) {
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: That would be obvious, but I don't believe it's very simple to enforce id's upon <tr/>'s with JSF and RichFaces...

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention there can be more rows. I want it for all rows for that table.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
jQuery('#scheduleForm:rowList>tr').click(function(event) {
            alert(1);
        });
```

and it will be better didn't use charter ":" in value of id attribute.I didn't know exactly< but i think it can be the reson of many problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have a colon `:` in an ID attribute. Colon has a special meaning in jQuery selectors, so you need to escape it like this:

```
jQuery('#scheduleForm\\:rowList tr').click(function(event) {
      alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The : is generated by JSF. 
You can also set prependId="false" on the form. Then just use:

```
jQuery('#rowList tr').click(function(event) { alert('hello'); });
```

and only that table will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#rowList").on("click", "tr", function(event) { 
    alert($(this).id); 
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.